# How Add new column in hive table which contains data?

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I want to add a new column which contains data in my existing hive table, I used alter table but I am getting some weird results. I have csv file contain data like:-

### Id      Name   Location

### "567381","Arjun",Amsterdam

### "567356","Rohan",London

### "567398","Sweta",Paris

and I want to add new column bankname "CNI_EW" but when I adding it into table I am getting result as mentioned below and the table headers are also mentioned:-

### "bank     id     name      location

### 567381  Arjun   Amsterdam null

### 567356  Rohan   London    null

### 567398  Sweta   Paris     null

### null    null    null      null

### null    null    null      null

### CNI_EW  575497  Ragini    Delhi

### CNI_EW  564573  Ashu      Spain"

Please let me know how I can correct it. I have to load a huge csv file in hive table with new column in existing hive table.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: The hive table is just a structure imposed onto a file.  Does the file behind the table contain the data?

Comment: The file behind the doesn't contains the data corresponding to the new column which I have added using alter command

Comment: did you use delimiter ',' in your table in hive

Comment: yes, these are csv file loaded into hdfs.